# datetime throwing value error in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert datetime format of a column in dataframe in python 
original date - 16-Jul-2018 00:00
final date- 2018-08-16 00:00

```
results['Date1']=dt.datetime.strptime(str(results['Date']), "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

but it is giving me value error. When trying specific string in syntex, it works
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
result['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(result['Date1'], format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M").dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Input:

```
               Date1
0  16-Jul-2018 00:00
```

Output:

```
              Date1
0  2018-07-16 00:00
```